# What does he say in this clip?

Tags: vocabulário

In this video https://jovemnerd.com.br/nerdoffice/top-10-personagens-doces/
at 24:40 Azaghal says 
"A vida e como ..."
but I don't think he says a box of chocolates. 
What does he say?

Comment: "A vida é como um saco de balas Fini. Abriu. Sorriu" Ele fala com certa clareza, não emenda muito as palavras. Mas pena que o stackexchange não armazena áudios para falantes nativos narrarem certas frases, e permitir que outros ouçam pronúncias diversas.

Comment: Falo espanhol e gosto de ouvir este podcast porque, como vc diz eles sempre falam com clareza e entendo a maioria do programa. Mais não sou brasileiro e portanto não conheço as marcas de doce do Brasil! Também me parece estranho que o caramelo e chamado "bullet"!

Comment: bullet ou bala ? Não usamos "bullet" no Brasil.

Comment: Pois é, Julian, aos portugueses também nos parece curioso que os brasileiros chamem "balas" aos rebuçados. :) Estas diferenças são muito interessantes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No video é dito:

> A vida é como um saco de balas Fini: abriu, sorriu!

Lembrando que Fini é uma marca de balas vendida no Brasil.